# Preserve whitespace between attributes in Python Xml file

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, attributes, whitespace

I'm using xml.dom.minidom to edit an xml file and need to preserve whitespace.  This works well for space between tags, but doesn't work for the attributes in the tag.   Is there any way this could be done?

Comment: What code are you using?  Would you mind sharing?

Comment: Problem is poorly described now. Please, add some your code snippets, expected result, actual result. This doesn't mean that you need copy-paste your whole project, but only related snippets, which show the problem.